# Can't connect to db on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am following the "getting started" instructions for deploying Rails to Heroku, and I am running into problems when trying to access the DB.

Steps taken:

1) Create a new project

```
rails new pdfl_4 -d postgresql
rake db:create:all
```

2) Add to git

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push
```

3) Push to Heroku

```
heroku login
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

4) Try to connect to the db

```
heroku pg:psql
```

Everything works ok until the last step. Error msg reads "psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out"

Seems like I'm missing something basic here, but not sure what it is.

Comment: Have you added the postgres addon? (https://addons.heroku.com/catalog/heroku-postgresql). If so, what's the output of `heroku pg:info`?

Comment: Yep, addon installed. Here's the output:

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 0
PG Version:  9.1.6
Created:     2012-12-03 03:03 UTC
Data Size:   5.9 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a Windows issue. My buddy was able to connect to my db from his Mac.

I used Taps to push the local db to Heroku which worked just fine
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-taps

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on [heroku documentation for `heroku pg:psql`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pgpsql),

> you must have PostgreSQL installed on your system to use `heroku pg:psql`

Follow the instructions for the [local setup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) to get it up and running locally.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run

```
 heroku run rake db:migrate
```

or

```
 heroku db:push  #this will push your ocal db to heroku
```

?